# Laravel Spark custom form request not found during API call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-spark

I have created a new form request using:

```
php artisan make:request
```

But when doing an API call I am getting:

```
Class App\Http\Requests\UpdateTeamPasswordRequest does not exist
```

In my controller I have it:

```
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateTeamPasswordRequest;

...

public function updatePassword(UpdateTeamPasswordRequest $request, $teamId)
{

}
```

And the class itself:

```
class UpdateTeamPasswordRequest extends FormRequest {
    ...
}
```

I have another form request that is included and used exactly the same for another purpose and it works fine, is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

A typo in the form request caused this issue:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'password' = 'required|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

Swapping out the = to => solved this.